# Select @field From table as parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, parameter-passing

I have a database table with some columns like "col_a", "col_b" and I want to retrieve just one column of it. But the column is depended on some user selection. Some times could be the col_a, the col_b, c .... 
So my question is if I can select a field from a table as parameter?
I want to set the @colName like this...

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsOrderErrors" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CS %>" SelectCommand="SELECT @colName AS fld FROM [a_table]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="colName" QueryStringField="colName" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

or in code behind.
Any idea?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do here.. Can you elaborate a little please

Comment: Column or table names cannot be parameters. You'd need to set the `SelectCommand` programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If doing it from codebehind works then you can do something like

```
sdsOrderErrors.SelectCommand = string.Format("SELECT {0} AS fld FROM [a_table]", colName);
```

(OR) Have a stored procedure to accept a parameter and perform a dynamic query to achieve the same like

```
create procedure usp_testSelect(@colname varchar(30))
as
begin
declare @sql varchar(200);
set @sql = 'select '+ @colname + ' AS fld FROM [a_table]';
exec(@sql);
end
```

Then use this procedure in your ASP.NET `SQLDataSource`